# AWS codebuild is failing due to long path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, devops-services

Trying to build asp.net application using AWS Codebuild.
While doing NuGet restore, getting the following error.

`Could not find a part of the path: C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src667194343\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\DirectTrees\DIRECTREESCMS-CODE\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.1.0\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.1.0.nupkg`

I suspect this is because path length is more than 256 character, is there any way I can reduce this path?

`C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src667194343\src\git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\` Source code is getting down load at this path and then all the comand in buildspec.yml file are getting executed.
Is there any way to reduce this path?

Hoping for some guidence from the community.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I Solved it my moving the CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR folder. My windows container is using powershell so you might need to change "$env:" to match your shell in the following snippet.

e.g. my buildspec.yml

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
     ....
     - mkdir c:\build\
     - mv $env:CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/* c:\build\
build:
   commands:
    - '& cd c:\build'
    - ...
```